# Booting to a command window without GUI

Tags: gnome

In the middle of installation issues with graph-tool for python, I gave the laptop a break and the keyboard started recognizing delete button on its own - meaning it kept deleting what I typed on the login menu.

I have seen cases when laptops would write many things when I would type just one letter - I never knew how to address them. So I restarted it, the best way I knew how,

Now it boots to a complete black screen, where I can log on, but I do not even understand why this is happening.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtYbT.jpg)

Could I hear some explanation as to why this is happening? Another weird thing about my Ubuntu is that it shows the numerous lines of status and processes when I start or turn-off. And I read that the temperature is too high, but it isn't. Maybe it was before..but not now at least.

Also, how do I restore the GUI setting?

Comment: What does "In the middle of installation issues" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you may not have properly installed your desktop environment or somehow your system crashed during installation. I would suggest reinstall gnome desktop environment (first install classic gnome desktop environment)

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```